# Using an if loop to exclude entries containing a substring

Tags: python, selenium, for-loop, if-statement, continue

I'm trying to scrape the results & statistics from the last 4 seasons of snooker from https://cuetracker.net.

I succeeded (somewhat) in scraping most of the data however I neglected to recognise that there are walkovers included. These walkovers contain only nationality,player name and score data and no stats and therefore as I have scraped my data in lists they do not correctly align when I convert them into a DataFrame.

I am trying to use a if in statement in my loop in order to try and skip these matches that are walkovers and therefore realign the correct stats with the correct match. I'm trying to use the word 'Walkover' to stop the item being appended to my list.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import os
import re
import time
import pandas as pd


def wait_for_page_load():
    timer = 15
    start_time = time.time()
    page_state = None
    while page_state != 'complete':
        time.sleep(0.5)
        page_state = browser.execute_script('return document.readyState;')
        if time.time() - start_time > timer:
            raise Exception('Timeout :(')


chrome_path = r"C:\Users\George\Desktop\chromedriver.exe"
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
page_source = browser.page_source

browser.get("https://cuetracker.net/seasons")
links = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("table.table.table-striped a")
hrefs=[]
for link in links:
    hrefs.append(link.get_attribute("href"))

hrefs = hrefs[1:2]

hrefs2 = []

for href in hrefs:
    browser.get(href)
    wait_for_page_load()
    links2 = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('.//tr/td[2]/a')
    for link in links2:
        hrefs2.append((link.get_attribute("href")))

player_1_nationality = []
player_1_name = []
player_1_score = []
player_2_score = []
player_2_nationality = []
player_2_name = []
date_played = []
player_1_points_scored = []
player_2_points_scored = []
player_1_fifty_plus_breaks = []
player_2_fifty_plus_breaks = []
match_progress = []
player_1_points_per_frame = []
player_2_points_per_frame = []


for href in hrefs2:
    browser.get(href)
    wait_for_page_load()
    list_1_nationality= browser.find_elements_by_xpath('.//div/div[2]/div[1]/b/img')
    for lis in list_1_nationality:
        player_1_nationality.append(lis.get_attribute("alt"))
    list_1_player = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('.//div/div[2]/div[1]/b/a')
    for li in list_1_player:
        player_1_name.append(li.get_attribute('text'))
    list_2_nationality = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('.//div/div[2]/div[3]/img')
    for nationality_2 in list_2_nationality:
        player_2_nationality.append(nationality_2.get_attribute("alt"))
    list_2_name = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('.//div/div[2]/div[3]/a')
    for name_2 in list_2_name:
        player_2_name.append(name_2.get_attribute('text'))
    list_1_score = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('.//div/div[2]/div[2]/span[1]/b')
    for score in list_1_score:
        player_1_score.append(score.get_attribute('innerText'))
    list_2_score = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('.//div/div[2]/div[2]/span[3]')    
    for score_2 in list_2_score:
        player_2_score.append(score_2.get_attribute('innerText'))
    #list_date_played = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('.//div[4]/div[2]/div/div') 
    #for date in list_date_played:
        #date_played.append(date.get_attribute('innerText'))
    page_source = browser.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, 'lxml')
    points_scored_elem = soup.find_all('div', text='Points Scored') 
    for elem in points_scored_elem:
        player_1_points_scored.append(elem.find_next('div').find_next('div').find_next('div').get_text())
    points_scored_2_elem = soup.find_all('div', text='Points Scored') 
    for elem in points_scored_2_elem:
        player_2_points_scored.append(elem.find_next('div').find_next('div').find_next('div').find_next('div').get_text())
    fifty_plus_breaks_elem = soup.find_all('div', text='50+ Breaks') 
    for elem in fifty_plus_breaks_elem:
        player_1_fifty_plus_breaks.append(elem.find_next('div').find_next('div').find_next('div').get_text())
    fifty_plus_breaks_2_elem = soup.find_all('div', text='50+ Breaks') 
    for elem in fifty_plus_breaks_2_elem:
        player_2_fifty_plus_breaks.append(elem.find_next('div').find_next('div').find_next('div').find_next('div').get_text())
    match_progress_elem = soup.find_all('div', text='Match progress') 
    for elem in match_progress_elem:
        match_progress.append(elem.find_next('div').find_next('div').find_next('div').get_text(strip=True))
    points_per_frame_elem = soup.find_all('div', text='points/frame') 
    for elem in points_scored_elem:
        player_1_points_per_frame.append(elem.find_next('div').find_next('div').find_next('div').get_text())
    points_per_frame_2_elem = soup.find_all('div', text='Avg. points/frame') 
    for elem in points_scored_elem:
        player_2_points_per_frame.append(elem.find_next('div').find_next('div').find_next('div').find_next('div').get_text())
    points_scored_2_elem = soup.find_all('div', text='Avg. points/frame') 
    for elem in points_scored_2_elem:
        player_2_points_per_frame.append(elem.find_next('div').find_next('div').find_next('div').find_next('div').get_text())
    list_date_played = soup.find_all('div', text='Played on') 
    for date in list_date_played:
        date_played.append(date.find_next('div').find_next('div').find_next('div').get_text(strip=True))
```

The above code is the bulk of my scraping code. Below is what I'm trying to test in order to skip the walkovers. I'm trying to use the parent of the img as it includes the 'Walkover' string within it's innerText.

```
for href in hrefs2:
    browser.get(href)
    wait_for_page_load()
    page_source = browser.page_source
    list_3_nationality = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('.//div/div[2]/div[1]/b/img')
    for lis in list_1_nationality:
        check = lis.find_element_by_xpath(("./parent::b"))
        check = check.get_attribute('innerText')
        if 'Walkover' in check:
            continue
        else:
            player_1_nationality.append(lis.get_attribute('alt'))
```

For some reason this doesn't seem to be working?

Comment: Your bulk code is broken at line 67; the `if` statement is not complete.

Comment: Apologies that was from me playing with it to try and solve this. It's actually as edited (hopefully).